# How do I use Not in a If statement with more than one condition

Tags: vb.net, delphi

Working on a old legacy code using VB or delphi, do not know for sure.  I am trying to write-- if itemA does not equal 111 OR itemA does not equal 222 then future date cannot be entered  if these itemaA 111 and 222 are enterend, then future date will be excepted. If itemA equals 333,444,123, etc and the date entry is in future date, it will not allow it.  The syntax is wrong somewhere.

```
   If NOT (itemA =  111) or not (itemA = 222) then

       if dateEntered > Date then
  
           Dialog ('Future date not allowed for item.');
      end if
  end if
```

Comment: Is this VBScript or VB.NET? Please tag accordingly.

Comment: Probably what you want is either `itemA <> 111 AndAlso itemA <> 222` or `Not (itemA = 111 OrElse itemA = 222)`.  (If you're working in VBScript and not .NET, then use "And" or "Or" in place of "AndAlso" or "OrElse".)

Comment: @ZevSpitz the posted code isn't any sort of VB at all.  It looks like Pascal or Delphi or something with the "begin" and "end".

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved.

Instead of

```
 if not (itemA = 111) or not (itemA=222) then...
```

It worked with

```
if not ((itemA = 111) or (itemA=222)) then ...
```

The parentheses did the trick

Answer (score 0):

The VB code, from what you have written, would look something like:

```
If itemA <> 111 Or itemA <> 222 Then
    ...
End If
```

Or, alternatively, and perhaps more clearly:

```
If Not (itemA = 111 And itemA = 222) Then
    ...
End If
```

However, neither of these options makes sense as the condition always resolves to True: `itemA` cannot simultaneously equal 111 *and* 222. The correct logic should be the other way around, eg:

```
If itemA <> 111 And itemA <> 222 Then
    ...
End If
```

But I don't think what you're actually after is VB code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the original logic is wrong. I mean you can do this in vb:

```
   If Not (itemA = 111) Or Not (itemA = 222) Then
        If dateEntered > Date.Today Then
            MsgBox("Future date not allowed for item.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
```

But I don't think that is or was original correct. The above if will ALWAYS be true since one or the other always going to occur?

I think you need this:

```
    If Not (itemA = 111) And Not (itemA = 222) Then
        If dateEntered > Date.Today Then
            MsgBox("Future date not allowed for item.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
```

The above is a 1 to 1 conversion here. (and yes that does look like delphi).

As noted, one could perhaps write this as :

```
    If (itemA <> 111) And (itemA <> 222) Then
        If dateEntered > Date.Today Then
            MsgBox("Future date not allowed for item.")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
```

But as noted using "or" for this does not seem to make sense. It's possible that delphi does or did a bit-wise OR - but that still does not seem to make much sense.